# S3 video play in edge and react native but not chrome or firefox

Tags: amazon-s3, html5-video

one of the user of the app I work for has an issue, all the video she upload doesn't work in an HTML5 video player, except on Edge and Safari for iOS (and if it works there I assume it could work in other browsers)

The video can be played in our react-native app or after being downloaded, but not directly using the S3 or cloudfront link

Since the vieos from the other users work, I'm assuming it's related to encryption and S3 specifications, does anyone have met this problem and found a solution ?

EDIT: forgot to put a sample link
https://video-reetags.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/compressed/aed0a512a419334fe5d0c0c6fb4094a21610642052.mp4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the videos from the other users are working fine, I'm assuming it's related to encryption and/or S3 specifications...

No, the problem is not encryption or S3 server issues.

Your MP4 container has video in HEVC format (aka H.265), which is **not supported** in Chrome or Firefox. You should still be able to hear the sound part since AAC audio is supported.

Playing the video is possible with React-Native and other (native) video players because they rely on the O.S running the player App to decode video. If a browser brand didn't buy a license for HEVC then that browser cannot play it.

**Solution**:
Re-encode such videos to MP4 containing H.264 with AAC audio (...not H.265  with AAC). 
Re-encoding takes time but it's the only way for now. Either the user does it before any uploading, or your own app accepts any file and re-encodes the "not supported" ones on server-side (*eg:* using FFmpeg or GStreamer tool).

Comment: You're right, the videos are supposed to be re-encoded through ffmpeg to avoid this issue but it's look like there's a way to bypass it and upload it without re-encoding
Thanks !